# Последний положительный элемент массива

Tags: массивы, visual-c++

Как находится последний положительный элемент в одномерном массиве?

Заранее спасибо. )

Comment: @ПашаРомашкин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Заводится доп. переменная. Затем перебирается массив с конца. При переборе каждый элемент массива проверяется, положителен ли он (сравнивается с 0). Если элемент >0, то его значение записывается в доп. переменную, и выходим из цикла. В доп. переменной будет содержаться значение последнего положительного элемента. Весь алгоритм.